# not able to use web worker

Tags: javascript, web-worker

I am in React project but not one created using `create-react-app`.

I am trying to start playing with web worker but i am so lost in the basic process.

[image]

This is my project directory where my file is under

```
 src
   vumi
     MapLayer.js
```

and the worker code is in

```
 src
    workers
       main.js
```

Webpack version is more than 5 so i believe i dont need worker-loader and webpack-dev-server version is 4.*

Inside MapLayers.js

```
const myWorker = new Worker("../workers/main.js");
console.log("worker is", myWorker);
myWorker.onerror = (e) => {
  console.log("there is error", e);
};
myWorker.postMessage(["hi", "i am pravin"]);

myWorker.onmessage = (e) => {
  let message = e.data;
  console.log("Message received from worker", message);
};
```

and in workers/main.js is

```
onmessage = (e) => {
  console.log("Message received from main script");
  console.log(e.data);
  const workerResult = `Result: ${e.data[0]} ${e.data[1]}`;
  console.log("Posting message back to main script");
  postMessage(workerResult);
};
```

my console.log() output with this code is

[image]

[image]

I am not able to understand what is error because i am not getting console.log() from worker and i believe it is not getting code of imported of worker in new Worker() because i was expecting to find the code of worker somewhere.

and this is tsconfig.json

```
{
  "extends": "create-extension/tsconfig/tsconfig.json",

  "include": ["./src/**/*"],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "rootDir": "./src",
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "lib": ["dom"],

    // Additional TypeScript error reporting checks are enabled by default to improve code quality.
    // Enable/disable these checks as necessary to suit your coding preferences or work with
    // existing code
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noUncheckedIndexedAccess": false,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true
  }
}
```

I am sorry if this is very vaque question,

Comment: Your worker never loads. You have to add it's code to the public folder

Comment: HI @Konrad, thank you so much for responding !! I made a public folder and moved the worker folder inside public and building the code give this error https://ibb.co/1sK89hZ
I changed the worker to  const myWorker = new Worker("workers/main.js"); but still getting same error